# Book series about invisible children

Tags: story-identification

There’s a series I remember reading back when I was in middle school, about a bunch of kids turning invisible (or like they were on a different “plane” of existence that could still interact with the rest of the world, but they couldn’t be seen, like the world had different layers). I’m pretty sure the title was a single word

Comment: 'Midnighters' by Scott Westerfeld? They can interact with a 'blue hour' at midnight.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnighters_trilogy

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is **very terse** and would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)